# DirectShare API with Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm trying the new "push" model for the direct share targets of Android Q. I'm using ShortcutMaangerCompat from Android X package as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/sharing). I removed the old direct share service too. I  tested my app on previous versions to check if backward compatible, it seems ok. On Android Q emulator I always get the "direct share not available". See image. Is it a bug? Emulator problem? Just me? I don't understand if I did something wrong with my app since I can't see *any* direct share targets on android Q.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, [this project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.5/ShareTargets) (from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q)) worked for me on Android Q hardware. IIRC, I tested the sharing using `adb shell am`.

Comment: What do you mean with "android q hardware"? A real phone?

Comment: In addition how did you test using adb? I'm trying using the emulator

Comment: "A real phone?" -- yes, specifically a Pixel running Q. "In addition how did you test using adb?" -- as I wrote, I believe that I used `adb shell am`, with an `Intent` that matched my shortcut `Intent`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just tried your code and it doesn't work on the emulator exactly same problem so I guess it's an emulator problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is indeed Android Q Emulator issue**. I ran the same sample app in Pixel Phone with Android 10, it works just fine showing the Contacts correctly in the place of where it showed "Direct Share not available" in Emulator.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SharingShortcuts